# Update Solidity - 0.5.4 (ERC20 + ERC677)

Tags: tokens, erc-20, erc-223, solidity-0.5.x, erc-677

I'm trying to create an ERC20 Token that can send Tokens to a Receiver Contract similar to how ERC223 does and i decided to try ERC677 but i can't understand how to update this code to match Solidity 0.5>. I'm using the Draft from ERC677 repo at https://github.com/smartcontractkit/LinkToken

When i update the code to match Solidity 0.5.4, i get an error for payable address that can be found in `ERC677Token contract > transferAndCall` at `super.transfer. The error i get is:

```
TypeError: Member "transfer" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address.
    address(super).transfer(_to, _value);
```

What's wrong ? Do i need to make the ERC20 balances payable ?

#### ERC20 Token + ERC677:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.4;

library SafeMath {
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        if (a == 0) { return 0;}
        uint256 c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b);
        return c;
    }
    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b > 0);
        uint256 c = a / b;
        return c;
    }
    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b <= a);
        uint256 c = a - b;
        return c;
    }
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        require(c >= a);
        return c;
    }
    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b != 0);
        return a % b;
    }
}
contract linkERC20Basic {
  uint256 public totalSupply;
  function balanceOf(address who) public view returns (uint256);
  function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}
contract linkERC20 is linkERC20Basic {
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns (uint256);
  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}
contract ERC677 is linkERC20 {
  function transferAndCall(address payable to, uint value, bytes memory data) public returns (bool success);

  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value, bytes data);
}
contract ERC677Receiver {
  function onTokenTransfer(address _sender, uint _value, bytes memory _data) public;
}
contract linkBasicToken is linkERC20Basic {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  mapping(address => uint256) balances;

  /**
  * @dev transfer token for a specified address
  * @param _to The address to transfer to.
  * @param _value The amount to be transferred.
  */
  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Gets the balance of the specified address.
  * @param _owner The address to query the the balance of. 
  * @return An uint256 representing the amount owned by the passed address.
  */
  function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
  }

}
contract linkStandardToken is linkERC20, linkBasicToken {

  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;


  /**
   * @dev Transfer tokens from one address to another
   * @param _from address The address which you want to send tokens from
   * @param _to address The address which you want to transfer to
   * @param _value uint256 the amount of tokens to be transferred
   */
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    uint _allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];

    // Check is not needed because sub(_allowance, _value) will already throw if this condition is not met
    // require (_value <= _allowance);

    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = _allowance.sub(_value);
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Approve the passed address to spend the specified amount of tokens on behalf of msg.sender.
   * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param _value The amount of tokens to be spent.
   */
  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Function to check the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
   * @param _owner address The address which owns the funds.
   * @param _spender address The address which will spend the funds.
   * @return A uint256 specifying the amount of tokens still available for the spender.
   */
  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining) {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
  }
  
    /*
   * approve should be called when allowed[_spender] == 0. To increment
   * allowed value is better to use this function to avoid 2 calls (and wait until 
   * the first transaction is mined)
   * From MonolithDAO Token.sol
   */
  function increaseApproval (address _spender, uint _addedValue) 
    public returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = allowed[msg.sender][_spender].add(_addedValue);
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }

  function decreaseApproval (address _spender, uint _subtractedValue) 
    public returns (bool success) {
    uint oldValue = allowed[msg.sender][_spender];
    if (_subtractedValue > oldValue) {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = 0;
    } else {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = oldValue.sub(_subtractedValue);
    }
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }

}

contract ERC677Token is ERC677 {

  /**
  * @dev transfer token to a contract address with additional data if the recipient is a contact.
  * @param _to The address to transfer to.
  * @param _value The amount to be transferred.
  * @param _data The extra data to be passed to the receiving contract.
  */
  function transferAndCall(address payable _to, uint _value, bytes memory _data)
    public
    returns (bool success)
  {
    super.transfer(_to, _value);
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value, _data);
    if (isContract(_to)) {
      contractFallback(_to, _value, _data);
    }
    return true;
  }


  // PRIVATE

  function contractFallback(address _to, uint _value, bytes memory _data)
    private
  {
    ERC677Receiver receiver = ERC677Receiver(_to);
    receiver.onTokenTransfer(msg.sender, _value, _data);
  }

  function isContract(address _addr)
    private
    returns (bool hasCode)
  {
    uint length;
    assembly { length := extcodesize(_addr) }
    return length > 0;
  }

}
contract LinkToken is linkStandardToken, ERC677Token {

  uint public constant totalSupply = 10**27;
  string public constant name = 'ChainLink Token';
  uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
  string public constant symbol = 'LINK';

  constructor() public {
    balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
  }

  /**
  * @dev transfer token to a specified address with additional data if the recipient is a contract.
  * @param _to The address to transfer to.
  * @param _value The amount to be transferred.
  * @param _data The extra data to be passed to the receiving contract.
  */
  function transferAndCall(address payable _to, uint _value, bytes memory _data)
    public
    validRecipient(_to)
    returns (bool success)
  {
    return super.transferAndCall(_to, _value, _data);
  }

  /**
  * @dev transfer token to a specified address.
  * @param _to The address to transfer to.
  * @param _value The amount to be transferred.
  */
  function transfer(address _to, uint _value)
    public
    validRecipient(_to)
    returns (bool success)
  {
    return super.transfer(_to, _value);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Approve the passed address to spend the specified amount of tokens on behalf of msg.sender.
   * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param _value The amount of tokens to be spent.
   */
  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value)
    public
    validRecipient(_spender)
    returns (bool)
  {
    return super.approve(_spender,  _value);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Transfer tokens from one address to another
   * @param _from address The address which you want to send tokens from
   * @param _to address The address which you want to transfer to
   * @param _value uint256 the amount of tokens to be transferred
   */
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value)
    public
    validRecipient(_to)
    returns (bool)
  {
    return super.transferFrom(_from, _to, _value);
  }


  // MODIFIERS

  modifier validRecipient(address _recipient) {
    require(_recipient != address(0) && _recipient != address(this));
    _;
  }

}

contract Token677 is linkStandardToken, ERC677Token {
    string public constant name = "Example ERC677 Token";
    string public constant symbol = "ERC677";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    constructor(uint _initialBalance) public {
        balances[msg.sender] = _initialBalance;
        totalSupply = _initialBalance;
    }
}

contract Token677ReceiverMock {
    address public tokenSender;
    uint public sentValue;
    bytes public tokenData;
    bool public calledFallback = false;

    function onTokenTransfer(address _sender, uint _value, bytes memory _data)
    public {
      calledFallback = true;

      tokenSender = _sender;
      sentValue = _value;
      tokenData = _data;
    }

}
```

Hope someone is more knowledgeable and knows a safer way to approach this matter. I don't want to use standard ERC20 + proxy oracle that listens and updates after it receives events. I want to use something like ERC677 or ERC223. I'm open to hear pros and cons and best practices.

Thank you in advance !!!

Comment: I think you should cast it to `payable address` (not just `address`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Update***

`ERC223` never became a standard, mostly because of the function overloading collusions in several wallets and newer version of Solidity >= 0.8.

If you want your contract to automatically react to token transfers sent directly to them with just 1 call and without having to call `approve` first then `transferFrom` check out Chainlinks ERC677 Model from here: https://github.com/smartcontractkit/LinkToken/tree/master/contracts

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Ended up with an ERC223 implementation :)
Thanks !

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.2;

/** 
 * @title SafeMath
 * @dev Unsigned math operations with safety checks that revert on error.
 */
library SafeMath {
    /**
     * @dev Multiplies two unsigned integers, reverts on overflow.
     */
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        // Gas optimization: this is cheaper than requiring 'a' not being zero, but the
        // benefit is lost if 'b' is also tested.
        // See: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/pull/522
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        uint256 c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b);

        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Integer division of two unsigned integers truncating the quotient, reverts on division by zero.
     */
    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        // Solidity only automatically asserts when dividing by 0
        require(b > 0);
        uint256 c = a / b;
        // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold

        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Subtracts two unsigned integers, reverts on overflow (i.e. if subtrahend is greater than minuend).
     */
    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b <= a);
        uint256 c = a - b;

        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Adds two unsigned integers, reverts on overflow.
     */
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        require(c >= a);

        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Divides two unsigned integers and returns the remainder (unsigned integer modulo),
     * reverts when dividing by zero.
     */
    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b != 0);
        return a % b;
    }
}

contract ERC223Interface {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address who) external view returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
    function transfer(address to, uint256 value, bytes calldata data) external returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) external returns (bool);
    function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) external returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value, bytes data);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

contract ReentrancyGuard {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    uint256 private _guardCounter;

    constructor () internal {
        _guardCounter = 1;
    }

    modifier nonReentrant() {
        _guardCounter = _guardCounter.add(1);
        uint256 localCounter = _guardCounter;
        _;
        require(localCounter == _guardCounter);
    }
}

contract ERC223ReceivingContract { 
    /**
     * @dev Standard ERC223 function that will handle incoming token transfers.
     *
     * @param _from  Token sender address.
     * @param _value Amount of tokens.
     * @param _data  Transaction metadata.
     */
    function tokenFallback(address _from, uint256 _value, bytes memory _data) public;
}

contract ERC223Token is ERC223Interface {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    address private _owner; // variables are not really private unless we are dealing with encrypted data
                            // https://medium.com/swlh/ethereum-aint-hiding-your-secrets-703e89088937

    string  public  constant name = "ERC223";
    string  public  constant symbol = "ERC223";
    uint8   public  constant decimals = 18;
    uint256 private constant _totalSupply = 10000000 * (uint256(10) ** decimals);

    mapping (address => uint256) private _balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowed;

    constructor() public {
        _owner = msg.sender;
        _balances[_owner] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), _owner, _totalSupply);
    }

    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
        return _balances[owner];
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(to != address(0));
        require(value > 0 && balanceOf(msg.sender) >= value);
        require(balanceOf(to).add(value) > balanceOf(to));

        uint256 codeLength;
        bytes memory empty;

        assembly {
            codeLength := extcodesize(to)
        }

        _balances[msg.sender] = _balances[msg.sender].sub(value);
        _balances[to] = _balances[to].add(value);

        if(codeLength>0) {
            ERC223ReceivingContract receiver = ERC223ReceivingContract(to);
            receiver.tokenFallback(msg.sender, value, empty);
        }

        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value, empty);
        return true;
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint256 value, bytes memory data) public returns (bool success) {
        require(to != address(0));
        require(value > 0 && balanceOf(msg.sender) >= value);
        require(balanceOf(to).add(value) > balanceOf(to));

        uint256 codeLength;

        assembly {
            codeLength := extcodesize(to)
        }

        _balances[msg.sender] = _balances[msg.sender].sub(value);
        _balances[to] = _balances[to].add(value);

        if(codeLength>0) {
            ERC223ReceivingContract receiver = ERC223ReceivingContract(to);
            receiver.tokenFallback(msg.sender, value, data);
        }

        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value, data);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool success) {
        _allowed[msg.sender][spender] = value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns (uint256) {
        return _allowed[owner][spender];
    }

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(to != address(0));
        require(value <= _balances[from]);
        require(value <= _allowed[from][msg.sender]);

        _balances[from] = _balances[from].sub(value);
        _balances[to] = _balances[to].add(value);
        _allowed[from][msg.sender] = _allowed[from][msg.sender].sub(value);
        emit Transfer(from, to, value);
        return true;
    }

    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public returns (bool success) {
        _allowed[msg.sender][spender] = _allowed[msg.sender][spender].add(addedValue);
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, _allowed[msg.sender][spender]);
        return true;
    }

    function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public returns (bool success) {
        uint256 oldValue = _allowed[msg.sender][spender];
        if (subtractedValue > oldValue) {
            _allowed[msg.sender][spender] = 0;
        } else {
            _allowed[msg.sender][spender] = oldValue.sub(subtractedValue);
        }
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, _allowed[msg.sender][spender]);
        return true;
    }

    function unlockERC20Tokens(address tokenAddress, uint256 tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        require(msg.sender == _owner);
        return ERC223Interface(tokenAddress).transfer(_owner, tokens);
    }

    function () external payable {
        revert("This contract does not accept ETH");
    }

}

contract ERC223Contract is ReentrancyGuard {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    ERC223Interface private token;

    function getBlockNumber() public view returns (uint256) {
        return block.number;
    }

    function getData() public pure returns (bytes memory) {
        return msg.data;
    }

    function getSignature() public pure returns (bytes4) {
        return msg.sig;
    }

    function () external {
      //if ether is sent to this address, send it back.
      revert();
    }

    function tokenFallback(address player, uint tokens, bytes memory data) public nonReentrant {
        emit DepositedERC223Token(player, tokens, data);
    }

    event Created(string, uint);
    event DepositedERC223Token(address from, uint value, bytes data);
}
```